# Nested TableView

Tags: qt, qml, tableview, qtquick2

I would like to created a nested TableView for some elements of my main TableView.
[image]

For example, if `Rowtitle == ""Brilliance"` , I would like to created a subTableView for this row.

```
ListModel {
    id: libraryModel
    ListElement {
        title: "A Masterpiece"
        author: "Gabriel"
    }
    ListElement {
        title: "Brilliance"
        author: "Jens"
    }
    ListElement {
        title: "Outstanding"
        author: "Frederik"
    }
}
TableView {
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "title"
        title: "Title"
        width: 100
       //if title==""Brilliance" create a second tableview
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "author"
        title: "Author"
        width: 200
    }
    model: libraryModel
}
```

Do you have any idea how to do it ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: does QTreeview meets your needs?

Comment: I will check but it seems so ! Thanks for the answer !